# error while trying to name column in select query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-10

I tried to run the following query earlier at work and I'm got an error that I didn't understand.

I've never encountered it before as I don't think I ever tried writing a `SELECT` query with aggregates that returned a column named `cost`.

Here's the sample data & schema

```
-- setup & sample data
CREATE TABLE test (cost NUMERIC(10,4));
INSERT INTO test VALUES (123), (234), (345);
-- query
SELECT SUM(cost) cost FROM test;
-- error message:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "cost"
LINE 1: SELECT SUM(cost) cost FROM test;
                         ^
```

Similarly, the following also return the same error:

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(cost) OVER () cost FROM test;
-- error message:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "cost"
LINE 1: SELECT FIRST_VALUE(cost) OVER () cost FROM test;
                                         ^
SELECT cost cost FROM test;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "cost"
LINE 1: SELECT cost cost FROM test;
                    ^
```

However when I explicitly use `AS` to name the expression, there are no issues:

Example (these all work fine):

```
SELECT cost AS cost FROM test;
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(cost) OVER () AS cost FROM test;
SELECT SUM(cost) AS cost FROM test;
```

I basically gave the aggregate a different name and everything was fine, but I'm curious why this is happening? I imagine there is some name collision happening, but I'm not sure what it is colliding against.

---

Here's my postgresql version / platform information giving the above error:

```
PostgreSQL 10.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit / Windows 10.
```

Also, I ran it on the following system (AWS RDS) and got the same error

```
PostgreSQL 9.6.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit
```

[Here is the example set up in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b2f88/1)

Comment: Interesting case, if you have a second field and try to use it as alias without `AS` works https://rextester.com/ABJOR99223

Comment: `cost` is a non-reserved keyword.  The use without `as` probably confuses the SQL parser.